# Submit form on blur using Django

Tags: jquery, angularjs, django, reactjs, django-forms

I am trying to create a page which contains a bunch of fields that can be updated by the user by clicking an Edit button (which will show the form for that field) and then changing the form.

Changes to the form (selecting an item from a dropdown list, for example) should be submitted to the backend as soon as they are chosen.

If you look at some of the settings pages on Facebook, you'll see roughly what I'm aiming for.

The site is built using django and I can obviously do this using jquery etc. but I'm wondering if it would make sense to use something like angular for this?

Or react maybe?

Is it sensible to spend time trying to learn something like angular (I've never used it) for this or is jquery the way to go, seeing as I only need a single page on my site?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the backend every time user performs an action can be done with jQuery like this:

```
// (Example) Add event listener on every .form-checkox element
$(document).on('change', '.form-checkbox', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   var fieldID = that.attr('id');
   var val = (that.is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
   update(fieldID,val);
});

// Perform ajax call
function update(field, value) {
   $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'path/to/handler',
      data: { field: field, value: value },
      success: function(data) {
         // Success action
      },
      error: function() {
         // Error handling
      }
   });
}
```

In the same way, you can add other event listeners for every field type in your form, and perform the ajax call each time a field gets updated by user.

You do not have to use Angular or React for such a simple interaction.